# install lxml 2.3 with python 3.2 on osx 10.6.8

Tags: python, osx-snow-leopard

I tried many times but still can not figure out how to install lxml into python 3.2

I'm using mac osx 10.6.8, gcc version 4.2.1

I install lxml using the following command

```
python3.2 setup.py build --static-deps
```

I always got errors as

---

```
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__Pyx_PyIndex_AsSsize_t’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:161563: error: ‘x’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:161563: error: ‘b’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:161565: error: invalid lvalue in assignment
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:161566: error: syntax error before ‘)’ token
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:161566: error: syntax error before ‘)’ token
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:161566: error: syntax error before ‘)’ token
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:161566: error: syntax error before ‘)’ token
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:161566: error: syntax error before ‘)’ token
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: At top level:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:161570: error: syntax error before ‘*’ token
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:161570: error: syntax error before ‘ival’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__Pyx_PyInt_FromSize_t’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:161580: error: ‘ival’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: At top level:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:161584: error: syntax error before ‘__Pyx_PyInt_AsSize_t’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:161584: error: syntax error before ‘*’ token
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c: In function ‘__Pyx_PyInt_AsSize_t’:
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:161585: error: ‘x’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:161588: error: syntax error before ‘val’
src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:161593: error: syntax error before ‘val’
lipo: can't figure out the architecture type of: /var/folders    /3o/3ozga0d2GXy7aa8oMPgJNU+++TI/-Tmp-//ccr3DFwu.out
error: command 'gcc-4.0' failed with exit status 1
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try: STATIC_DEPS=true sudo easy_install --allow-hosts=lxml.de,*.python.org lxml
     or the instructions @ http://lxml.de/installation.html#installation

Comment: I tried,    STATIC_DEPS=true sudo easy_install --allow-hosts=lxml.de,*.python.org lxml
Password:
Searching for lxml
Best match: lxml 2.3
Processing lxml-2.3-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg
lxml 2.3 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/lxml-2.3-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg
Processing dependencies for lxml
Finished processing dependencies for lxml

Comment: It seems always using py2.6. I want to install into python3.2

Comment: Sorry I installed it a while ago and don't want to give you a definitive answer as it was a long time ago.  I do remember running into issues as well and I eventually figured it out.  Check out this link, someone has simalir problems and outlines how they resolved it: http://codespeak.net/pipermail/lxml-dev/2010-July/005558.html